# Git-lab OAuth plugin -logout link not working

Tags: jenkins, oauth-2.0, jenkins-plugins, gitlab

We configured Gitlab oauth plugin in my Jenkin server ,Now i can log with my gitlab credential in Jenkins but logout option not working once signed .

Already below issue reported in Github OAuth plugin but now this same issue in gitlab plugin too.please any one log this issue in Jenkin

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16350

Comment: You mean that somebody should write the bug report for the Gitlab plugin for you? Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @StephenKing ,I could not able to sign up Jenkin site,that's why you guys anyone please log this issue in Jenkins if you have an account already.

Comment: Then register an account at jenkins.io please. Come on.. seriously.

Comment: @StephenKing,We facing below issue in Jenkins.IO

Comment: Due to the spam problem, we will need additional verification for your sign-up request. More details are found on our wiki on how to get your account created.

Comment: Have you read that wiki page? Thanks for your efforts to report that bug. Sorry for being a bit hash maybe.. I'm sure, Jenkins folks would like to make this easier for you, but they probably have reasons (other people misbehaving..) to make it a bit harder for you. Please don't give up - it's our responsibility as users of open source projects to support them as best as we can (I'm also just a "normal" Jenkins user).

Answer (score 0):

Because github server is not aware of  your Oauth app logging out mechanism,best way to achieve it is as below;

Provide a link (refer the code snippet,to test open in a new window or tab)
Include the local logout mechanism and also logout from the github simultaneously.

```html
<a href="https://github.com/logout">Logout</a>
```